# macOS list all VPNs without using `scutil`

Tags: macos, vpn

I saw this thread to check if we're connected to a VPN: [How can I tell if OS X is connected to a VPN network from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/577094/how-can-i-tell-if-os-x-is-connected-to-a-vpn-network-from-the-command-line)

The accepted answer uses `scutil --nc list`. Unfortunately this commands shows me, on macOS Mojave 10.14.3:

```
$ scutil --nc list
Available network connection services in the current set (*=enabled):
```

Another user also has the same output on [his blog](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/vpn_connected.php).

Are there any other ways to list all the VPNs configured under System Preferences?

Comment: What type of VPN service is it (i.e. L2TP over IPSec, Cisco IPSec, IKEv2, or something else)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm really not that knowledgeable about VPNs. I'm talking about the ones listed here https://imgur.com/a/eh2jK3U, in System Preferences -> Network

Comment: For me, `scutil --nc list` does not list ipsec connections on macOS 12.5 (21G72) Monterey.